# 3 space Object as x gets large

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having a bit of trouble visualizing an object given  $(a \cdot \cos(t), a \cdot \sin(t), ct)$ where c and a are constants. What object is described as c becomes large compared to a?

Comment: It's a helix or corkscrew. The size of $a$ is the radius of the screw, and $c$ determines the pitch. The bigger $c$ gets, the steeper the pitch of the screw.

Comment: Oh ok. What is the object when c is equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

This is an equation of Helix where a is the radius .. Please see the figure  [image]

Contribution from x and y shown here in red and blue. Middle you can see the helix. When c >>> it may look like a line (not exactly).. The length of winding will be less dense

Answer (score 0):

remember that $(cos(t),sin(t))$ describes a circle counterclockwise around the origin of radius 1 and period $2\pi$.  adding a factor of $a$ scales the radius of the circle (and can change the direction of flow if a is negative$.    $ct$ is linear in the z direction, so what you have is a spiral going out from the origin,  along a cylinder of radius a.